Short or "Medium" Date format produces "Sept" for September on a Windows 11 Machine - bad VB code but ... what causes this behaviour?
In our software we occasionally need to pass a date and time value in some sort of String format which may end up being used in SQL and converted back to a DATETIME.
I wish it weren't so, but it is what it is, there's a legacy aspect to this that we cannot change.
So in order to avoid problems I've insisted that if this needs to be done, people need to convert the date and time value to the "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss" format
But of course there's always that one developer who "forgets" to do this, and VB is so darned forgiving....
Dim startDate As DateTime
'something here sets it to an actual date and time, say the 26th of September 2024 11:12:13
Dim sStartDate as String
'This is what they SHOULD be doing:
sStartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
'But this is what they actually did
sStartDate = startDate 'leaving it up to VB to "kindly" convert it to a Short Date/Time format

Because our clients are all UK/Irish this has never been a problem and this particular piece of code (or something very similar) has worked for hundreds of people without a glitch. As a result of what they actually did the string becomes "26 Sep 2024 11:12:13" and when this gets sent to a SQL server and converted to a DATETIME it's perfectly fine.
Years pass
Suddenly we get a support call from a client where this isn't working. When we investigate the problem we find that the date and time value is not converted to "26 Sep 2024 11:12:13", but instead it's converted to "26 Sept 2024 11:12:13". And SQL throws a hissy fit.
So what we need to do is obvious. I need to rap somebody's knuckles, fix the code that doesn't explicitly set the date format during the conversion, fix the SQL Stored Procedure that accepts the string value to handle "June", "July" and "Sept". But I'm left with a question...
My question
Where is this configured on the user's PC? We looked at their regional settings (It's a Windows 11 machine) and they look the way they should.

There doesn't even seem to be a setting that would produce 26 Sep 2024? Like a "medium date format"? A setting that might produce "26 Sept 2024" instead?
I can't believe I need to ask this question - and I had a bit of a google but I can't find anyone with the same problem on Windows. Not on Stack Overflow nor elsewhere. If this is a duplicate I apologise... I didn't find any original question that deals specifically with this issue in Windows 11 and/or Visual Basic.

(To fix the code, note that it should pass the date as a DateTime to the stored procedure. That way it will also work with different UI languages. Also, make sure to set Option Strict On otherwise strange unexpected things can happen.)

Do the same settings show if you go Control Panel (use the icons view) -> "Region"? I suppose maybe the control panel version could differ from the regional format settings. Also, what format does the user see if they hover the mouse over the date at the end of the Task Bar?

The code actually produces an XML string in which the date/time is presented as an attribute. By ensuring that such attributes are always set using the yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss format this is easily converted back to a datetime format when the SQL procedure uses the MS t-sql methods that allow us to read XML as if it's "ordinary" SQL data

I'll ask our support guy to check what the user sees the next time he gets to connect to their machine.

So yes I should have mentioned that the databases are Azure or On Premises SQL Server

If the support guy connects with an account that isn't the user's, they might not see the user's regional settings. I could be wrong.

I believe they are using one of those remote support thingies that allow you to join the user's session while the user is working on their PC

I am also having the same issue now, it seems to have originated with Windows 11 24h2 update been applied to PC's. So where this update is I get "SEPT" but in 23h3 and prior I am getting "SEP". This is a major issue for us as our code base is ancient and horridly written.
My guess is that an internal resource for our locale was accidentaly updated from "Sep" to "Sept" and deployed with 24h2

That would not surprise me one bit. Like yourself, we have code going back a decade or more, some of it written by... er... let's say "not the sharpest tools in the shed". But even so, it worked for all our customers for ten long, blissful years so yeah, would not be surprised at all if this was caused by 24h2

Hello all. Just wanted to post this to let you know. I just updated my PC to Windows 11 24H2 and I can confirm that when you go to your Windows Settings >>> Time & Language >>> Language & Region >>> Regional Format and you click "Change Formats" and you change the Short Date Format (if in UK or Ireland) from 05/04/2017 to 5 Apr 2017 (why that date, I don't know) and you  write an app that relies on implicit conversion for a date like 2024-09-14, it will show 14 Sep 2024 on older Windows versions and 14 Sept 2024 on 24H2

I see we are not the only ones who've come up against this problem:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-did-windows-11-24h2-update-change-english-new/fb872710-a1bb-4735-8131-bb83ca609e37

So after a lot of Googling and searching I think I finally have an answer and it's all due to the standards set in the "Unicode CLDR Project"
It may be very new to us who are suddenly subjected to Windows 11 24H2, but in fact this standard has been around for years. If you go googling for "September changed from Sep to Sept" you will find people coming up against this issue for years on many different platforms. I found one such complaint dating back to 2015 and who knows there may be earlier ones.
Long story short:
With regard to this standard, Microsoft is actually "late to the party". Others implemented it a LONG time ago.
All we can do is ask our clients to delay applying Windows 11 24H2 until we get around to fixing our software so it can handle this properly. Thankfully this turned out to be not as big a deal as I feared.
My apologies to anyone who came here hoping to find a "fix" but the only thing I can do is provide the answer to the question as stated. This is why it happened. We have to learn to live with it.

Got confirmation from Microsoft that this is indeed the result of a push to comply with Unicode CLDR Project.
